# RemoveHander does not work for sub within structures?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

> This works:

```
Private Sub DisplaySomeText(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
    Debug.Print("Display some text")
End Sub

Private Sub Load_Handlers
    AddHandler textbox1.textchanged, AddressOf DisplaySomeText
End Sub

Private Sub Clear_Handlers
    RemoveHandler textbox1.textchanged, AddressOf DisplaySomeText
End Sub
```

> This does not work (for me at least):

```
Structure typMyHandlers
    Public Sub DisplaySomeText(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
        Debug.Print("Display some text")
    End Sub
End Structure

Private MyHandlers as typMyHandlers 'or MyHandlers as New typMyHandlers, tried both

Private Sub Load_Handlers
    'Actually this bit still does work
    AddHandler textbox1.textchanged, AddressOf MyHandlers.DisplaySomeText
End Sub

Private Sub Clear_Handlers
    'It's this part that seems to get ignored
    RemoveHandler textbox1.textchanged, AddressOf MyHandlers.DisplaySomeText
End Sub
```

---

It seems as though (at least in the application I'm working on now) the RemoveHandler command gets ignored when the specified sub is part of a structure.

Note I haven't actually tested the above code specifically so forgive any typos but I think you'll get the idea. Also in my case I've got structure within structure so it might work one level down but cease to work once its handler within structure within structure... either way it seems a bit strange that AddHander works for the control and sub, but RemoveHandler only works when the sub is not enclosed within a structure.

Is this a known bug or am I missing something?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct

Comment: The link from @HansPassant does provide the info (in microsofts usual dry fashion). If  you declare the structure as a class and instantiate it using Private MyHandlers as New typMyHandlers, it works just fine.

Comment: I thank you both for the reason - it also answers the question that was just on the cusp of my mind that was the difference between classes and structures. The ByRef and ByVal being the main difference that I could wrap my tiny mind around.
The more I understand, the more I realise I don't understand.